# Why does a car need so much power to get to a given speed compared to an aircraft?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft

This question has been bothering me for a long time because it seems like it should be obvious, but I can't figure it out.  Excuse me if I'm being dumb.

Why does a car require so much more power then an aircraft to hit, say, 200mph?

For example, a Mooney 201 (M20J) has 200hp, and can hit 175kts (201mph).  I have done some research and it seems that some automobiles need over 450hp to break the 200mph barrier, many much more then that.

I can't seem to dig up a cross sectional frontal area of the mooney 201, but visually it looks like it has as much or more surface area straight on then a car would.

Another thought I had was that it was because cars need down force to grip the road, but airplanes need to expend energy to keep themselves in the air, at least 1G worth of lift.  Only serious race cars can generate 1G of down force, and gravity is in the cars favor, even if it's aerodynamically neutral, it still has 1G of force giving it grip.  The aircraft always has to fight gravity and impart enough force on the air to generate its own weight in lift, thus causing drag.

So what is it?  Are airplanes, not governed to fit into small brick shapes like cars are, just that much more efficient? If you made a car that looked like an airplane, would it only need a small amount of power to reach 200mph?  Or are losses from wheels having to impart force on the ground a lot greater then I thought they were?

I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of something.

Comment: I would guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance ("For example, in earth gravity, a car of 1000 kg on asphalt will need a force of around 100 newtons for rolling (1000 kg × 9.81 m/s2 × 0.01 = 98.1 N).") Also, your Mooney seems of lighter weight than an average car.

Comment: Are you comparing air speeds, or ground speeds?

Comment: keep these mind: Does that 100 newtons scale up with speed?

rob:  I was assuming no tail wind or headwind, so would these not be the same speeds?

Comment: An interesting little [online calculator for HP required for different car parameters](http://www.wallaceracing.com/Calculate%20HP%20For%20Speed.php).  Using it I found that you could in theory design a car using the experimental settings and for maybe a single person (small frontal area) that did 200mph on 200HP.  Experiment with it.  Rolling resistance on that calculator seems to run at about the 15-20% mark.

Comment: StephanG:  Okay, so based on this, I guess airplanes have a lot less equivalent frontal area then cars and that's all it really is to it, give or take 15-20%, if I understand what I'm seeing here?  Thank you, by the way.